# How to fix dependency on devm_kmalloc for the phy driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to build a custom phyDriver in my Ubuntu Machine - 18.04.
The kernel version is  5.3.0-40. 
However, I get errors on insmod like -

The dmesg tells me -

```
57810.400155] phyDriver: module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.
[57810.400156] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[57810.400196] phyDriver: Unknown symbol devm_kmalloc (err -2)
[57810.400234] phyDriver: Unknown symbol platform_driver_unregister (err -2)
[57810.400555] phyDriver: Unknown symbol __platform_driver_register (err -2)
```

I am unsure why I am getting `devm_kmalloc()` unknown symbol.
I am using `devm_kzalloc()` and I believe this is complaining about `devm_kzalloc()`.
My question is how do I solve this problem. Do I need to build kernel to add those debug symbols
or is there any other easy way? If I have to build kernel then what I need to enable in the kernel
so that my driver can access these symbols like - `devm_kzalloc()` `platform_driver_register()`

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
static int phy_platform_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) { 

  struct custom_port_phy_platform_local *lp;
    int ret;

    lp  = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev,sizeof(struct custom_port_phy_platform_local),GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!lp) {
      dev_err(&(pdev->dev),"Failed to allocatate platform_local\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, lp);

    lp->dev = &pdev->dev;
    ret = custom_port_phy_mdio_setup(lp, pdev->dev.of_node);
    if (ret < 0) {
      dev_err(&(pdev->dev),"Failed to setup MDIO bus\n");
      return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}


static int __init phy_init(void)
{
   int ret = 0;
   ret = phy_driver_register(&custom_phy_driver, THIS_MODULE);
   if(ret < 0) {
       printk(KERN_ALERT "custom phy driver registration failed\r\n");
       return ret;
   }

   ret = platform_driver_register(&custom_phy_platform_driver);
   if(ret < 0) {
       phy_driver_unregister(&custom_phy_driver);
       printk("%s: Failed to register as Platform Driver\r\n", __func__);
       return ret;
   }

   return ret;
}

static struct platform_driver custom_phy_platform_driver = {
 .probe = phy_platform_probe,
 .remove = phy_platform_remove,
 #if 0
 .driver = {
    .name = "custom_port_phy"
    .of_match_table = port_phy_of_match,
 }
 #endif
};

module_init(phy_init);
```

Here is my makefile.

```
obj-m += phyDriver.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

I ran 'make all' to build the phydriver.ko.
Afterwards, I did sudo insmod phydriver.ko and I saw those errors in the dmesg.

Comment: Provide the details on how you built your kernel module.

Comment: It's not enough. You need to show more, i.e. how you use the mentioned `phy_init()` and `phy_platform_probe(), also *Makefile* and command line you run to build it. Besides you missed to tell what kernel version and do you have any patches on top of it?

Comment: About license is easy part, add `MODULE_LICENSE(...);` to your module.

Comment: `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)` is that how it's done nowadays? Shouldn't it be `M=$(PWD)`?

Comment: Thanks, I have added more details now. It doesn't make any difference whether you use SUBDIRS or M in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function from the kernel you want to use are licensed under GPL, see ex. [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6-rc4/source/drivers/base/platform.c#L794). To use GPL licensed functions from your module, your module needs to be licensed under GPL license too. That is what it means that GPL is a "copyleft" license - to use the code written under GPL (ie. those functions) you have to write your code under license compatible with GPL.

So if you feel like it license your module under GPL:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: how do I add the GPL licensing in my module in order to access it?

Comment: You add the line `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` anywhere at file scope to the source file of your module. Usually it's either on the end or at the beginning of source file. [Like this](https://github.com/almariah/kernel-module-example/blob/master/example.c#L42).